# Using Python's unittest module to test return values from instance methods of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, oop, python-unittest

```
class Solution:

    def addNums(self, a, b):
        return a + b

test1 = Solution()   
test1.addNums(5, 6)
```

The above is my class! With a simple add method.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is, prepare for Algorithms and Data Structures/Programming Interviews, where I create instance for each input and want to write unit tests for instances..

Here is what I've tried below:

```
import unittest

class TestSolution(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addNums(self):
        example = Solution()  
        self.assertEqual(example.addNums(9, 10), 19)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Not sure how to go about doing this, if I run the above code, I get this error message:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '/Users/abhishekbabuji/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-eb5f1d39-4880-49a7-9355-bbddc95464ff'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: True
```

I want to be able to test return values of an instance method of a `Solution` class, in this case `addNums(self, a, b)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running the following code:

```
import unittest

class Solution:

    def addNums(self, a, b):
        return a + b


class TestSolution(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addNums(self):
        example = Solution()  
        self.assertEqual(example.addNums(9, 10), 19)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

produces

```
.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Edit: The following should work on jupyter.

```
import unittest

class Solution:

    def addNums(self, a, b):
        return a + b


class TestSolution(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_addNums(self):
        example = Solution()  
        self.assertEqual(example.addNums(9, 10), 19)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=['ignored', '-v'], exit=False)
```

Comment: Did you run this in a Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I used raw python.

Comment: I think [this]([https://medium.com/@vladbezden/using-python-unittest-in-ipython-or-jupyter-732448724e31) is what is going on.

Comment: Yeah! You are right! I marked my own question as a duplicate! Thanks man. Here, take an upvote

Comment: updated the code. just tried on jupyter. seems to work.